# Handling contextual links from restful api in vuejs

Tags: rest, vue.js, hyperlink

Apparently I haven't used the correct search terms, because I can't find anything like my issue..

In Vuejs I use axios tot consume a restful API, the results can contain contextual links to ie complete a task. How do I handle these GET requests from the frontend?

This is what my response looks like:

```
      {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "iPhone",
        "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/orders/2"
          },
          "orders": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/orders"
          },
          "cancel": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/orders/2/cancel"
          },
          "complete": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/orders/2/complete"
          }
        }
      }
```

I've tried this (which obviously doesn't get me the needed result):

```
    <md-table v-model="orders" :table-header-color="tableHeaderColor">
      <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ item }">
        <md-table-cell md-label="Description">{{
          item.description
        }}</md-table-cell>
        <md-table-cell md-label="Status">{{ item.status }}</md-table-cell>
        <md-table-cell md-label="Action">
          <a v-if="item._links.complete" :href="item._links.complete.href">
            Complete
          </a>
        </md-table-cell>
      </md-table-row>
    </md-table>
```

All I did find some information about is binding links to the router.. But that all seems to be about non conditional links, my API can omit certain links if they don't apply.

Comment: Can you show console error?

Comment: You have item._links.complete.href. How do you assign HAL object to the item variable?

Comment: Do you have some problem with reactivity or what?

Comment: The issue is that this just renders the uri given in the response. What I would like is using the GET request asynchronously.

Comment: I still don't understand your issue. I supposed you use axios to get the HAL object. Am I right? Where and when do you assign HAL object to the item variable?

Comment: The uri is a API GET call that initiates an action via the API. I don't want the browser to follow this uri.

Comment: Do you want to stop browser follow some url after click on the some link?

Comment: I want to make the GET request anyschronously

Comment: ok, now I got it. 1 minute.

Comment: You can check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your link this:

```
<a v-if="item._links.complete" :href="#" @click.prevent="clickHandler($event, item._links.complete.href)">
```

Within your vue component methods add new method:

```
methods:{
    clickHandler(event, yourUrl){
        axios.get(yourUrl)
        .then(function (response){
            //do what you need with this response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MartijnICU , I have finished. You can check updates.